# Display QSQLite database using QStandardItemModel in qt

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt5, qtableview

I have a `QSQLite` database from which I have read all the values. Now, I want to display the entire database onto a `QTableView` using `QStandardItemModel`.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

This answer does not try to respond directly to the question, since I think there are better options that the author does not know, but I try to guide him to choose a better option. Therefore, I propose the following:

To display the information of a database in a QTableView it is advisable to use [`QSqlTableModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html).

> The QSqlTableModel class provides an editable data model for a single
>   database table.
>
> QSqlTableModel is a high-level interface for reading and writing
>   database records from a single table. It is built on top of the
>   lower-level QSqlQuery and can be used to provide data to view classes
>   such as QTableView.

For example:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
if (!db.open())
    qDebug()<< "Cannot open database"

QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel;
model->setTable("person");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->select();

QTableView view;
view.setModel(model)
```

For more information I recommend reading the following:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-model.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-cachedtable-example.html

The advantages of this option:

- The class recognizes fields and their types automatically.
- Also be used to access a database programmatically, without binding it to a view.
- If you need to add filters you must use [`setFilter()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setFilter) and if you require ordering you can use [`setSort()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setFilter).

Answer (score 1):

The [QStandardItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#details) class provides a generic model for storing custom data.

This is an example for QStandardItemModel:

```
if(db.isOpen())
{
    QStandardItemModel *standardModel = new QStandardItemModel();
    QSqlQuery query(db);
    query.prepare("SELECT * FROM DayLog ORDER BY ID");
    if(query.exec())
    while(query.next())
    {
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(query.value("date").toString());
        standardModel->appendRow(item);
    }
    ui->tableView->setModel(standardModel);
}
```